# UIImageView array frame equality

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

I have two `NSMutableArray`s with `UIImageView`s in it. I am wondering how to check if the frames of the `UIImageView`s are equal to the frames of the other array in Objective-C. Is there a function for this?

Comment: There is no built-in method that does exactly what you're asking for. What have you tried, and what part are you stuck on? Is it comparing CGRects, or iterating through each array, or what? Are the corresponding views in the same order in each array, or might they be different?

Comment: they are in the same order in each array.
I tried this `[array1 isEqualToArray:array2]` in an if statement. But I found that some properties of the arrays are different from each other .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming arrays are the same length and are called `array1` and `array2`.

```
__block BOOL equal = YES;
[array1 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIImageView *imageView, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    UIImageView *otherImageView = array2[idx];
    if (!CGRectEqualToRect(imageView.frame, otherImageView.frame))
    {
        equal = NO;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];

if (equal) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you are doing here?

Comment: It iterates through every UIImageView in one array, finds the corresponding UIImageView from another array, and checks if their frames are equal. After the block has executed, we have a BOOL called equal that we can use in an if statement.

Comment: The only problem is that I use a NSTimer to check if the frames are equal to each other.